# Brand Filter by Category in shopping django rest

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am facing problems on filtering `Brand` by `Category` in Django Rest Framework.

```
class Category(TimeStamp):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='category_icons', null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)



class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    brand_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='brand_images', null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
```

here I have two models. For example I have a Category like `Clothing -> Foot Wear -> Shoes` if user enter `Clothing` category I should get all brands in `Clothing` but when I go to `Shoes` section I should get all brands in `Shoes` category. For this How can I write `query_set`? Any help would appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add a related name to category foreign key

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, related_name="brands")
```

Then

```
clothing_category = Category.objects.get(name="Clothing")
clothing_brands = clothing_category.brands.all()

shoe_category = Category.objects.get(name="Shoes")
shoe_brands = shoe_category.brands.all()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer `clothing_category` works fine but `shoe_brands` return empty QuerySet

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Are you sure you have a category with the name "Shoes"?